# Title Heading for Tree R Package

Tags: r, plot, tree

I want to add a main title heading to the plot output of a `tree` model.

```
library(tree)
data(cpus, package="MASS")
cpus.ltr <- tree(log10(perf) ~ syct+mmin+mmax+cach+chmin+chmax, cpus)
cpus.ltr
summary(cpus.ltr)
plot(cpus.ltr, main="test")
text(cpus.ltr, main="test")
```

Alas, I do not seem to have a heading.

[image: no heading :(]

How do I add a title?

Comment: You should be able to use `mtext`  and play with the parameters: `mtext("test", side = 3, font = 2, cex = 1.2, line = 1)`, if `plot.tree` does not use/pass the main attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use title

```
library(tree)
data(cpus, package="MASS")
cpus.ltr <- tree(log10(perf) ~ syct+mmin+mmax+cach+chmin+chmax, cpus)
cpus.ltr
summary(cpus.ltr)
plot(cpus.ltr)
text(cpus.ltr)
title("test")
```